# Communication entre ARDUINO NANO 33 BLE SENSE?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new and I would really need your experience and your help : Here is my project:

I’m trying to make 2 Arduino nano 33 ble sense communicate:I need to send the accelerations and gyro data from the first one and receive them in the second, How i can did ?

The idea is to do 6 Arduino nano 33 ble sense each associate with an electrochemical technology sensor (UART), and send the data tram to the central board which will retrieve all the informations from the differents sensors via BLE on each board.

Then I will associate with the central card (the one which recovers all the informations of the 6 cards) a LORA module to send the data to a PC (I would like to do it in real time).

Thank you .

Comment: It seems like you want your 6 arduino to work as peripheral devices and your central device as central. There are many tutorials on arduino +BLE on the internet, you can start with this one: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/monica/getting-started-with-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-ab4c94

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse rapide, Cependant moi je veux faire les test entre les 2 arduinos nano 33 ble sens: Par exemple, détecter la température de la première carte et de l'envoyer à la seconde carte en temps réel?   sur votre lien c'est comment associer une carte arduino 101 avec un télephone sachant que moi je travail sur une carte arduino  NANO 33 BLE SENSE , Esperant que quelqun dans la communauté arduino nano à déja trvailler sur ça .

Comment: I don't speak french so I translated it. I hop it worked well enough to understand what you mean. You need to program one arduino as a BLE peripheral, the other as BLE central device. find even more examples here: https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBLE/tree/master/examples I don't know if it's possible to connect 6 arduinos to one central device, this depends on your central device. Please try to work with the examples and come back with a new question if something does not work out. Stackoverflow will help you with a concrete problem but won't do everything for you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, I managed to communicate two cards at the same time with the examples of arduino nano

-File → Examples → ArduinoBLE → Peripheral → LED

-File → Examples → ArduinoBLE → Central → LEDControl

But for example I haven't yet known how to transfer the information on the temperature sensor from the first Arduino nano 33 ble sense board and read them on the second
nano 33 ble sense.
Why sensor of Temperature ?
Because after  I am going to have another sensor that I am going to associate with the nano 33, that's why In first, I need to try with the temperature or humidity sensor of nano 33.   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can find an excellent short tutorial on the link below about connecting two Arduino nano using BLE. One acting as peripheral device and the other as central device.

*"In this tutorial, we will learn how to exchange information between two Arduino boards, the Nano 33 BLE and the Nano 33 BLE Sense, through Bluetooth® Low Energy. For this, we will be using the ArduinoBLE library."*

**code for programming the central device**

```
/*
  BLE_Central_Device.ino

  This program uses the ArduinoBLE library to set-up an Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense 
  as a central device and looks for a specified service and characteristic in a 
  peripheral device. If the specified service and characteristic is found in a 
  peripheral device, the last detected value of the on-board gesture sensor of 
  the Nano 33 BLE Sense, the APDS9960, is written in the specified characteristic. 

  The circuit:
  - Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense. 

  This example code is in the public domain.
*/

#include <ArduinoBLE.h>
#include <Arduino_APDS9960.h>

const char* deviceServiceUuid = "19b10000-e8f2-537e-4f6c-d104768a1214";
const char* deviceServiceCharacteristicUuid = "19b10001-e8f2-537e-4f6c-d104768a1214";

int gesture = -1;
int oldGestureValue = -1;   

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  
  if (!APDS.begin()) {
    Serial.println("* Error initializing APDS9960 sensor!");
  } 

  APDS.setGestureSensitivity(80); 
  
  if (!BLE.begin()) {
    Serial.println("* Starting BLE module failed!");
    while (1);
  }
  
  BLE.setLocalName("Nano 33 BLE (Central)"); 
  BLE.advertise();

  Serial.println("Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense (Central Device)");
  Serial.println(" ");
}

void loop() {
  connectToPeripheral();
}

void connectToPeripheral(){
  BLEDevice peripheral;
  
  Serial.println("- Discovering peripheral device...");

  do
  {
    BLE.scanForUuid(deviceServiceUuid);
    peripheral = BLE.available();
  } while (!peripheral);
  
  if (peripheral) {
    Serial.println("* Peripheral device found!");
    Serial.print("* Device MAC address: ");
    Serial.println(peripheral.address());
    Serial.print("* Device name: ");
    Serial.println(peripheral.localName());
    Serial.print("* Advertised service UUID: ");
    Serial.println(peripheral.advertisedServiceUuid());
    Serial.println(" ");
    BLE.stopScan();
    controlPeripheral(peripheral);
  }
}

void controlPeripheral(BLEDevice peripheral) {
  Serial.println("- Connecting to peripheral device...");

  if (peripheral.connect()) {
    Serial.println("* Connected to peripheral device!");
    Serial.println(" ");
  } else {
    Serial.println("* Connection to peripheral device failed!");
    Serial.println(" ");
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("- Discovering peripheral device attributes...");
  if (peripheral.discoverAttributes()) {
    Serial.println("* Peripheral device attributes discovered!");
    Serial.println(" ");
  } else {
    Serial.println("* Peripheral device attributes discovery failed!");
    Serial.println(" ");
    peripheral.disconnect();
    return;
  }

  BLECharacteristic gestureCharacteristic = peripheral.characteristic(deviceServiceCharacteristicUuid);
    
  if (!gestureCharacteristic) {
    Serial.println("* Peripheral device does not have gesture_type characteristic!");
    peripheral.disconnect();
    return;
  } else if (!gestureCharacteristic.canWrite()) {
    Serial.println("* Peripheral does not have a writable gesture_type characteristic!");
    peripheral.disconnect();
    return;
  }
  
  while (peripheral.connected()) {
    gesture = gestureDetectection();

    if (oldGestureValue != gesture) {  
      oldGestureValue = gesture;
      Serial.print("* Writing value to gesture_type characteristic: ");
      Serial.println(gesture);
      gestureCharacteristic.writeValue((byte)gesture);
      Serial.println("* Writing value to gesture_type characteristic done!");
      Serial.println(" ");
    }
  
  }
  Serial.println("- Peripheral device disconnected!");
}
  
int gestureDetectection() {
  if (APDS.gestureAvailable()) {
    gesture = APDS.readGesture();

    switch (gesture) {
      case GESTURE_UP:
        Serial.println("- UP gesture detected");
        break;
      case GESTURE_DOWN:
        Serial.println("- DOWN gesture detected");
        break;
      case GESTURE_LEFT:
        Serial.println("- LEFT gesture detected");
        break;
      case GESTURE_RIGHT:
        Serial.println("- RIGHT gesture detected");
        break;
      default:
        Serial.println("- No gesture detected");
        break;
      }
    }
    return gesture;
}
```

**code for programming the peripheral device**

```
/*
  BLE_Peripheral.ino

  This program uses the ArduinoBLE library to set-up an Arduino Nano 33 BLE 
  as a peripheral device and specifies a service and a characteristic. Depending 
  of the value of the specified characteristic, an on-board LED gets on. 

  The circuit:
  - Arduino Nano 33 BLE. 

  This example code is in the public domain.
*/

#include <ArduinoBLE.h>
      
enum {
  GESTURE_NONE  = -1,
  GESTURE_UP    = 0,
  GESTURE_DOWN  = 1,
  GESTURE_LEFT  = 2,
  GESTURE_RIGHT = 3
};

const char* deviceServiceUuid = "19b10000-e8f2-537e-4f6c-d104768a1214";
const char* deviceServiceCharacteristicUuid = "19b10001-e8f2-537e-4f6c-d104768a1214";

int gesture = -1;

BLEService gestureService(deviceServiceUuid); 
BLEByteCharacteristic gestureCharacteristic(deviceServiceCharacteristicUuid, BLERead | BLEWrite);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);  
  
  pinMode(LEDR, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LEDG, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LEDB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  
  digitalWrite(LEDR, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LEDG, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LEDB, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

  
  if (!BLE.begin()) {
    Serial.println("- Starting BLE module failed!");
    while (1);
  }

  BLE.setLocalName("Arduino Nano 33 BLE (Peripheral)");
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(gestureService);
  gestureService.addCharacteristic(gestureCharacteristic);
  BLE.addService(gestureService);
  gestureCharacteristic.writeValue(-1);
  BLE.advertise();

  Serial.println("Nano 33 BLE (Peripheral Device)");
  Serial.println(" ");
}

void loop() {
  BLEDevice central = BLE.central();
  Serial.println("- Discovering central device...");
  delay(500);

  if (central) {
    Serial.println("* Connected to central device!");
    Serial.print("* Device MAC address: ");
    Serial.println(central.address());
    Serial.println(" ");

    while (central.connected()) {
      if (gestureCharacteristic.written()) {
         gesture = gestureCharacteristic.value();
         writeGesture(gesture);
       }
    }
    
    Serial.println("* Disconnected to central device!");
  }
}

void writeGesture(int gesture) {
  Serial.println("- Characteristic <gesture_type> has changed!");
  
   switch (gesture) {
      case GESTURE_UP:
        Serial.println("* Actual value: UP (red LED on)");
        Serial.println(" ");
        digitalWrite(LEDR, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LEDG, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(LEDB, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        break;
      case GESTURE_DOWN:
        Serial.println("* Actual value: DOWN (green LED on)");
        Serial.println(" ");
        digitalWrite(LEDR, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(LEDG, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LEDB, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        break;
      case GESTURE_LEFT:
        Serial.println("* Actual value: LEFT (blue LED on)");
        Serial.println(" ");
        digitalWrite(LEDR, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(LEDG, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(LEDB, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        break;
      case GESTURE_RIGHT:
        Serial.println("* Actual value: RIGHT (built-in LED on)");
        Serial.println(" ");
        digitalWrite(LEDR, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(LEDG, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(LEDB, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        break;
      default:
        digitalWrite(LEDR, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(LEDG, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(LEDB, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        break;
    }      
}
```

you can find the original tutorial here:

https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/nano-33-ble-sense/ble-device-to-device

there is also a really good explanation and *how to* here:

https://ladvien.com/arduino-nano-33-bluetooth-low-energy-setup/